# Chat high CPU usage and `replace is not a function`

Tags: bug, chat, firefox

When Chat such as https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253534/milp (nothing interesting about that; it's currently empty) is open in Firefox, it takes up high CPU:

[image: high cpu usage]

The console is constantly spamming this error:

[image: console error]

```
Uncaught Type Error: s.data.replace is not a function
```

My version of Firefox is 112.0.2 (64-bit).

The error does not appear in Chrome.

Narrowing this down to an extension, it appears to be caused by Adblock Plus 3.17; even disabling blocks on the site is not enough to remove the error - the plugin needs to be disabled entirely.

Comment: Can confirm this happens - having only chat tabs open started making firefox take up 8+GB of RAM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur8qY.png

Comment: That is not exactly a confirmation, that is a different symptom altogether. Console spewing an error and high CPU usage can be easily linked together, but 8gb of ram usage that is total insanity.

Comment: @lyxal What does `about:performance` show?

Comment: @lyxal IME, what you're describing is a different issue and a bug in Firefox. It's been happening for a couple of months now. The symptoms are that a single FF process maxes out one CPU core and consumes as much memory as possible, until Firefox crashes. If you catch it early, you can kill the single Firefox process which is taking up the memory and Firefox will recover, but the tabs which that process was handling will have crashed (no surprise) and need to be reloaded. I don't know if it's related to chat specifically, but I suspect not, as I haven't seen the issue reported in this question.

Comment: @Reinderien For the issue reported in this question: Do you have any extensions and/or userscripts installed? The code which the error points to is a `message` event handler and it's implying the data supplied (`s.data`) with the `message` event isn't a `String` (and, thus no `replace()` method), which is a bit strange, because the code does check that `s.data` is truthy.

Comment: Could you mention the version of Firefox? Just want to make sure that this is not something like [the browser does not support anymore due to internal change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372753/241919).

Comment: Interesting, norepro here on FF 112.0.2 without plugins.

Comment: Note: The file in which the error is occurring, master-chat.js, hasn't changed since sometime prior to 2020-12-28, so it's quite unlikely that the thing that's changed to cause this issue is in that file. That doesn't mean SE isn't loading other JavaScript into the page which is resulting in the error, but does make it less likely that this is caused only by the chat page (i.e. it's likely that your networking config, OS, browser, browser extensions, and/or userscripts are contributing to the issue).

Comment: Hum, no Repro *at the moment* (I often get FF to crash (currently v111.0.1_x64 + Win10_22H2), but usually related to FB and not SO). + 'uBlock Origin' v1.42.0 (=> not 'uBlock +'), with 20 pinned Tabs (loaded thus), 1800 Tabs open, of which *always* +[30-200] Tabs loaded, currently ~100 Tabs loaded (only 1 FB), Memory-Usage at ~2Gb, CPU <3%.